# Kinect Speech Recognition not detecting while in fullscreen

Tags: c#, fullscreen, speech-recognition, kinect, xna-4.0

This one is a weird case.  I'm using Microsoft.Speech with the Kinect in XNA.  Everything works as expected except for when I'm running the game in fullscreen on one monitor.  If I'm not fullscreen, or if I'm connected to another monitor via HDMI and in fullscreen mode, the Kinect detects and recognizes speech with no problems.  But as soon as I run the game in fullscreen, with no other HDMI connections,  Speech is never even detected, let alone recognized.  There are no errors in the initialization process.  To summarize:

- Windowed mode - Works as expected
- Fullscreen with second HDMI monitor connection - Works as expected
- Fullscreen with no other monitor connections - **No speech detection**

*Possibly related, possibly not, if I run the game (or any game for that matter) in fullscreen with the other monitor plugged in, the game can't render (keeps blinking on both monitors as if it's trying to enter and leave fullscreen repeatedly) but again, speech works fine in that case.*

Any thoughts?  All are appreciated, as usual.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you use a different machine and monitor?

Comment: Different monitor: yes. But apparently the problem did not persist when I attempted to repro on another laptop. So it must be something special about my machine?

Comment: I would have thought that it may be a problem with your laptop, but I am only guessing. Perhaps you could try to reinstall, but there would be no guarantee that it would work after all the hassle. My only other suggestion would be to check that the Kinect SDK is installed correctly, although I am sure it probably is since it is working some of the time, but worth a check. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572107/kinect-for-xbox-360-and-kinect-sdk-1-5/11585419).